# Finding the perfect damp for a sinusoid graph

Tags: exponential-function, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Below is a sinusoid function that is defined by this equation:
$ 9.36 \times\sin(0.95x-2.06)+13.64 $.
Would it be possible to create a function that produces a dampening close to the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qockq.png)

If this is not possible, can a fitting like this can be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RPzS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please don't rely on image links to define your question; please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem/34123#34123.

Answer (score 0):

They are not enough points and too large scatter for a good fitting.

Example of poor fit below of sinusoidal function damped with exponential.

[image]